# Referencing entries of matrix in R within for loop

Tags: r, syntax, matrix, reference, syntax-error

Is there a way to reference a part of a matrix within a for loop?

```
for (j in 1:x1)
  for (k in 1:x2) {
    matrix[j,8k-6:8k+1] <- AlleleFreq.t1[k,1:8]      
   }
}
```

I get an error message saying "unexpected symbol in "alldata.t1[j,8k".  What is the correct syntax for preforming this sort of operation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use parens & `*` to multiply:

```
 8k-6:8k+1   ~~~>  (8*k-6):(8*k+1)
```

---

the `seq` operator `:` takes precedence over arithmetic operators such as `-` 
Thus, without parens, you have

```
(8*k) - c(6, 7, 8) + ((8*k) + 1)
```

Comment: Parentheses aren't working. I still get the same unexpected symbol error

Comment: @Coho13, did you fix `8k` to `8*k` as well?

Comment: Nope.  got it now.  Thank you very much.